# Хранение ключ-значение в базе данных django и манипуляции ими

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite3, django-model

Всем добрый день/вечер/ночь, делаю сайт интернет магазина комп.комплектующих и возник такой вопрос, у меня есть прототипы моделей самого продукта:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, db_index=True)
    multiple_types_helper = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    tech_specs = models.ManyToManyField('TechSpec', related_name='tech_specs', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    short_desc = models.TextField(max_length=270, blank=True, null=True)
    full_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    carousel_2_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    carousel_3_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['category', 'name', ]
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'), )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} in {self.category}'
```

и его характеристик:

```py
class TechSpec(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    product_helper = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} -- {self.description}, products: {self.product_helper}'
```

Пример вывода в темплейт:[image: Пример]

Однако у разных продуктов может быть одна и та же характеристика, но с отличающимися данными, к примеру у другого кейса для ПК может быть размер не Mid-Tower, а Full-Tower и т.п., очевидно, что я хочу для такого кейса изменить значение характеристики, а не добавлять вручную новую характеристику с нужным значением, что я собственно делаю сейчас

Вопрос: Как проще всего реализовать в БД такое поле и как манипулировать его значениями в зависимости от реальных технических характеристик продукта

Comment: Ну вы же уже используете в моделях ForeignKeys. что мешает повторить?